# Python AES256 not decoding correctly

Tags: python, aes

I am having some issues with decoding AES256. I do some experimentation with couple of micro services that talk to each other.

```
import base64

from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Hash import SHA512
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes
import secrets
import random
import string
from Crypto.Util import Counter


def generateKey():
    key = base64.b64encode(secrets.token_bytes(16))
    iv = secrets.token_bytes(16)
    return key.decode("utf-8"), iv


def encryptAES(key, iv, raw):
    raw_2 = raw.encode("utf-8")
    cipher = AES.new(key.encode("utf-8"), AES.MODE_CFB, iv, segment_size=128)
    encrypted = base64.b64encode(iv + cipher.encrypt(raw_2))
    return encrypted.decode("utf-8")


def decryptAES(msg, key):
    raw_2 = msg.encode("ascii")
    iv = raw_2[:16]
    cipher = AES.new(key.encode("utf-8"), AES.MODE_CFB, iv, segment_size=128)
    cipher_decrypt = cipher.decrypt(raw_2[16:])
    cipher_decrypt_b64 = base64.b64encode(cipher_decrypt)
    return cipher_decrypt_b64.decode("utf-8")


initial_data = "Empty string"
keys = generateKey()
encrypted_data = encryptAES(keys[0], keys[1], initial_data)
print(encrypted_data)
print(decryptAES(msg=encrypted_data, key=keys[0]))
```

What is confusing for me that other Java service decrypts this

```
 public String decrypt(String encrypted_encoded_string, String KEY){

        String plain_text = "";
        try{
            byte[] encrypted_decoded_bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encrypted_encoded_string);
            String encrypted_decoded_string = new String(encrypted_decoded_bytes);
            String iv_string = encrypted_decoded_string.substring(0,16); //IV is retrieved correctly.

            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(Arrays.copyOf(encrypted_decoded_bytes, 16));
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(KEY.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CFB/NoPadding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);

            plain_text = new String(cipher.doFinal(Arrays.copyOfRange(encrypted_decoded_bytes, 16, encrypted_decoded_bytes.length)));//Returns garbage characters
            return plain_text;

        }  catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        return plain_text;
    }
```

Only python part seems not good :(
Is it about iv ?

I done some research, couldn't find an answer.

Thanks :)

EDIT working solution from answer:

```
def decryptAES(msg, key):
    raw_2 = base64.b64decode(msg)

    # raw_2 = msg.encode("ascii")
    iv = raw_2[:16]
    cipher = AES.new(key.encode("utf-8"), AES.MODE_CFB, iv, segment_size=128)
    cipher_decrypt = cipher.decrypt(raw_2[16:])
    # cipher_decrypt_b64 = base64.b64encode(cipher_decrypt)
    return cipher_decrypt.decode("utf-8")
```

Comment: In `decryptAES()` the ciphertext must be Base64 decoded *first* and *only then* separated: `raw_2 = base64.b64decode(msg)`. The decrypted data should not be Base64 encoded but UTF-8 decoded: `return cipher_decrypt.decode("utf-8")`.

Comment: Works like a charm! :) thank you! a cannot mark a comment as an answer, tight?

Comment: Note that this isn't AES-256. You create a random 16 bytes key, which you Base64 encode, resulting in a 24 bytes key. With this you encrypt/decrypt, which corresponds to AES-192, but with reduced security, because the Base64 alphabet contains only 64 characters.

Comment: I was aware that I reduce security, the reason is that i push the key via URL, so it has to be url safe. That is probably a bad idea although for experiment i did it anyway. By the way, Base64 does not give a fully url safe but for now its fine :)

Comment: You can still use AES-256 in your scenario. For this you have to generate a 32 bytes key. Keep the Base64 encoding when generating the key: `key = base64.b64encode(secrets.token_bytes(32))`. Before encryption and decryption the key has to be Base64 decoded: `cipher = AES.new(base64.b64decode(key),...`.

Comment: More critical seems to me the transfer of the key via url. Usually the key is sent over a secure channel or it is encrypted itself (e.g. RSA, see hybrid encryption). If the key is not passed securely, the whole encryption is pointless.

Comment: You are right! :) will consider that. Thank you.